# cloudwatch - group several log groups in one group

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a log group for every one of my three lambda functions. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to group the three log groups into just one group, this way it is much easier to follow my lambdas logs.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single log group and manually assign that log group to the lambda, using whatever method of deployment you are doing (Manual, Cloud Formation, CDK, ect ect).

This quickly becomes unwieldy however, as there are a lot of housekeeping logs that happen into your log groups. You're probably better off using Cloudwatch Dashboards and Log Insights to query your logs for the information you need, or in advanced cases, OpenSearch

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the best way to achieve easier troubleshooting is using elastic search/OpenSearch. You can use also log insights with some predefined queries in the shorter term.